# Initial and final chapters appearing in the table of contents without numbering

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, numbering, chapters

I'm editing a document whose preamble starts with

```
\documentclass [12pt, a4paper]{extbook}
```

I wish the chapter 'Introduction and its sections' appear in table
contents at the beginning of the text before the unnumbered chapter 1.

I also would like a chapter that I call 'Prelude' and its sections' appear in table
contents at the beginning of the text before the unnumbered chapter 1.

How can I do this?

> Introduction .................................................
>   .................
>
> ```
>              nontechnical introduction .........................
>
>              intrudução technique .................................
>
>              structure of the thesis ....................................
> ```
>
> Chapter 1 ................................................
>   ..................
>
> ```
>              Section 1 ..................................
>
>              Section 2 ..................................
>
>              Section 3 ..................................
> ```
>
> Chapter 9 ................................................
>   ................
>
> ```
>              Section 1 ..................................
>
>              Section 2 ..................................
>
>              Section 3 ..................................
> ```
>
> Prelude
>   ..................................................................
>
> ```
>              Other open issues .........................
>
>              New techniques ............................
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for the starred versions of the `\section`, `\part` etc and a `\addcontentsline{toc}{}{}`.

For example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{extbook}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter*{Introduction}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
        \section*{nontechnical introduction}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{nontechnical introduction}
        \section*{intrudução technique}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{intrudução technique}
        \section*{structure of the thesis}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{structure of the thesis}

    \chapter{Chapter 1}
        \section{Section 1}
        \section{Section 2}

    \chapter{Chapter 9}
        \section{Section 1}
        \section{Section 2}

    \chapter*{Prelude}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Prelude}
        \section*{Other open issues}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Other open issues}
        \section*{New techniques}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{New techniques}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

An easier solution is to use KOMA-script and the `scrbook`-class and utilise the `addchap`and `addsec` commands. They are similar to the standard commands `\chapter` and `\section` except that they are unnumbered. They produce both a running
head and an entry in the table of contents.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \addchap{Introduction}
        \addsec{nontechnical introduction}
        \addsec{intrudução technique}
        \addsec{structure of the thesis}

    \chapter{Chapter 1}
        \section{Section 1}
        \section{Section 2}

    \chapter{Chapter 9}
        \section{Section 1}
        \section{Section 2}

    \addchap{Prelude}
        \addsec{Other open issues}
        \addsec{New techniques}
\end{document}
```

[image]